# How do i check windows user log in?

Tags: windows, operating-system, user-controls

i need to build an application for find who try to log in to the pc with wrong user and password in windows 10. What is the service or shell should i read. Is it possible ?. Language is c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply read the eventlogs for failures as documented by Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/basic-audit-logon-events

event-id 529 is probably enough.